# Looking for an old sci-fi book/series about kids crashed on a planet

Tags: story-identification, books, soft-sci-fi

Ok, so it might be a long-shot, as I was around 12 when I read this book (or books?) — which was 30 years ago.

I'm not sure if it was a series of books, or just one book which I never finished.

The plot is about group of kids, going on a mission/tour in space and their spaceship crashes on a deserted planet.

I know it will probably ring as *Tunnel in the Sky*, but it's not that. I don't remember much, but here are some of the things that I do recall

1. The Safari suit — one of the kids insisted to get a Safari suit as a birthday gift, he wore it to the trip and he tells about it — a lot. I think it got tore and he buried it — but not sure.
2. If I remember correctly, the story is told through their diaries — as in, someone found their diaries years afterward and he is telling their story.

Now, this was 30 years ago, so I might have mixed some stories into one in my mind, but I'm pretty sure there were such books and would really like to find them.